# Pass arguments to script that is redirected to at

Tags: bash

I have a simple command:

```
/usr/bin/at -m now < /home/test/script.sh
```

I want to pass arguments to script.sh.

Unfortunately this isn't working:

```
/usr/bin/at -m now < /home/test/script.sh arg1 arg2
```

It throws error:

> syntax error. Last token seen: a
>
> Garbled time

Does anyone know how to do it? I've tried dozen of quotes, slashes and stuff like that for arguments. Each one of them throws different error.

Solution below won't work for me because I have to run it inside another bash script.

```
/home/test/script.sh arg1 | at now
```

Comment: Why is the pipe a problem when running in another script?

Comment: You're not executing `script.sh`, but rather passing the contents of the file `script.sh` into `/usr/bin/at`.    I'm not sure what the piping issue you're describing is.

Comment: This script is executed inside file called mount which is placed at /vz/private/$CONTAINER_UUID/scripts. The purpose of that is simple: I have to run a command during container start process (mount). Explanation for why am I using at command is also simple: it gives me ability to run this script asynchronously. Finally in the script which is executed by at command there is sleep command which just waits 15s to be executed after whole initalization of a container.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is, that you either execute `script.sh` or pass its source to `at`. But `at` just wants some command string like (literally) `script.sh args`.

Try bash's *here strings*

```
at now <<< "/home/test/script.sh arg1 arg2"
```

which is equivalent to

```
echo "/home/test/script.sh arg1 arg2" | at now
```